# How to use Neo4j in command prompt without running as administrator

Tags: windows, batch-file, neo4j, admin, command-prompt

I am trying to use Neo4j 3.0.3 (zip file) command line tools in the command prompt on Windows 10. The problem is that it won't execute the files unless I run the command prompt as administrator. This is an issue for me because I can't run the command prompt as administrator on my machine I use for production. How can I run the Neo4j command prompt tools (neo4j-import.bat, etc.) without administrator mode? Is it possible?

Comment: This seems purely system-based problem. Neo4j requires to have access to the network, to be able to listen on different ports for its shell, web interface, etc.

Comment: Is there anyway to not have to run the command prompt as admin though?

Comment: Can you please add the error message you have? It should help me to find a solution :)